# Why is my facebook app doesn't appear in recent activities?

Tags: facebook

Why when a user begins to use my application on Facebook not appear always in his recent activities? Appears in the feed of some users, but not in all users. Can my app post a recent activity manually?

Comment: As far as i know your app needs to be a canvas app and the stories are only created after a period of the user remaining on your app's page without leaving